# Mass rename of file extensions recursively (windows batch)

Tags: windows, recursion, batch-file, rename

I have numerous files in a very complex directory structure, and for reasons not worth discussing I need to rename all files with the extension of ".inp" to have ".TXT" extensions. There are numerous other files with other extensions that I do not want to be touched, and I want to do it recursively down at least 5 levels.

So far I have:

```
for /d %%x in (*) do pushd %%x & Ren *.inp *.TXT & popd
```

...but this only goes down one level of directories.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can someone supply Windows 10 solution?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
for /r startdir %%i in (*.inp) do ECHO ren "%%i" "%%~ni.txt"
```

should work for you. Replace `startdir` with your starting directoryname and when you've checked this works to your satisfaction, remove the `echo` before the `ren` to actually do the rename.

---

For the downvoters: executing a batch file differs from excuting from the command prompt in that each `%%x` where `x` is the metavariable (loop-control variable) needs to be reduced to `%`, so

```
for /r startdir %i in (*.inp) do ECHO ren "%i" "%~ni.txt"
```

should work if you execute this from the prompt. Please read the note about `echo`.

Comment: @Magoo... i think I love you. Thanks for this solution to a problem which took 2 days of my life, excellent work thanks!

Comment: i love this echo option. I was trying to run this, initially in a wrong directory. And echo option saved me.

Comment: I wish this explained what the `~ni` is for

Comment: @HDog : See the documentation `for /?` from the prompt. `~n` modifies the metavariable `i` to select only the `Name` part.

Answer (score 46):

On Windows 7, the following one-line command works for me, to rename all files, recursively, in *.js to *.txt:

```
FOR /R %x IN (*.js) DO ren "%x" *.txt
```

Comment: This worked, the selected answer didn't, said "%%i was inexpected". Thanks for this !

Comment: Got same error "%%i was inexpected" from the code in the accepted answer. Note you'll have to cd to the start directory

Comment: @SteveChamaillard : That's because the selected answer assumes the line is in a batch file. If it's executed from the prompt, you need to change each `%%` to `%`

Comment: @brunettdan : : That's because the selected answer assumes the line is in a batch file. If it's executed from the prompt, you need to change each `%%` to `%`

Answer (score 7):

John Smith's answer is excellent, and it works. But to be completely clear (I had to re-read magoo's notes to figure out the correct syntax), here is exactly what you need to do...

```
BATCH FILE:
FOR /R %%x IN (*.js) DO ren "%%x" *.txt

COMMAND LINE:
FOR /R %x IN (*.js) DO ren "%x" *.txt
```

Up vote their responses, I am but a lowly formater...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the renaming is necessary to change invalid characters inside the files and names. If you need to change a single character recursively:

Change character "╞" for "ã" in folder names recursively:

`FOR /R /D %x in (*╞*) do @for /f "tokens=1-3* delims=╞" %B in ("%x")  DO ren "%x" "%~nBã%C"`

Change character "╞" for "ã" in file names recursively:

`FOR /R %x in (*╞*.*) do @for /f "tokens=1-3* delims=╞" %B in ("%x")  DO ren "%x" "%~nBã%C"`

Change the chars for whatever you need. If you want to test your renaming commands before executing, just put an @echo between DO and ren:

`DO @echo ren "%x" "%~nBã%C"`

This will output the commands instead of executing them