# Specify directory location in batch code that would normally work the same folder as the .bat

Tags: batch-file

I have this code with works great if the .bat is located in the same folder as the files. Code came from: [.bat for batch rename to increment numbers in fname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322329/bat-for-batch-rename-to-increment-numbers-in-fname)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od *.cbr') do (
 echo ren "%%a" !count!.cbr
 set /a count+=1
)
```

I would like to specificity a directory where the above process can take place.

This is my code but I cannot get it to work.

```
%NewFolder% - it is specified in the code above this part. 

   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od "004 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%\"*.JPG') do (
 ren "004 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%\%%a" "004 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%\"!count!.JPG
 set /a count+=1
)
```

Comment: The help for `ren` states that "you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file", and by that it means the destination name is limited to just the base filename, e.g. `!count!.JPG`.

Comment: @eryksun Oh dear... Hmmm.. What would be a possible solution. I have the bat file located outside of the folder where I would like the process to take place. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want `ren "004 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%\%%a" !count!.JPG`. No?

Comment: @eryksun That is where all the files are. Yes. Thank you.

The process is just to rename all the files in a directory and increment by 1. The bat would not be located in the same directory.

Comment: `pushd "004 - Images Ready\%NewFolder%\"` before the `for` loop and remove all the directory stuff from the `for` loop. `popd` after the `for` loop

Comment: @eryksun, you may want to post your comments as an answer, so the OP could accept it...

Comment: @eryksun Of course. I am still working on it. Thank you.